# Updating the [Judaism] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [judaism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judaism) tag currently has the description:

> the monotheistic religion of the Jews.

Judaism has a several meanings:

- a religion,
- an ethnic group/nationality, and a
- a culture.

You can be someone who falls into one, two or three meanings.

- For example, converted Jews, secular Jews, Christians with a Ashkenazi genes.

The tag is also broadly in this way. Sometimes it's used for questions about purely religious matters:

- [Was the Pentateuch dated back to the second millenium B.C.E?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35431/was-the-pentateuch-dated-back-to-the-second-millenium-b-c-e)
- [Did a Jewish rabbi precisely calculate the duration of the full moon cycle 1800 years ago?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26907/did-a-jewish-rabbi-precisely-calculate-the-duration-of-the-full-moon-cycle-1800)

Sometimes it is used for questions that relate to the Jewish nationality:

- [Was the Jewish flag one of only two flags allowed in Nazi Germany?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32805/was-the-jewish-flag-one-of-only-two-flags-allowed-in-nazi-germany) (The question talks about a Jewish/Zionist flag which is a national flag and not a religious item).

I think that the description should include something along the lines of

> This tag can be used for question about the Jewish religion or the Jewish people.

And I wanted to consult about it.

Comment: This leads into a bigger problem which keeps miring the questions in this tag: that people don't make the distinction in the claims, leading inevitable quibbling about what was intended.

Comment: Do you have any reference for "Judaism" having a widely-accepted meaning of ethnic or culture contexts? (as opposed to "jewishness")? The fact that the questions are lazily mis-tagged isn't such evidence, it's just people not tagging right.

Comment: @user5341 not a reference but most of my self-identifying jew friends are not religious.

Comment: @Sklivvz - the point is, **are they identifying specifically as belonging to *Judaism* and not to *Jews/Jewish***, which are two different terms (at least in English, there's a chance in Italian it's same word which would explain the discrepancy?). In USA, I never heard of "Judaism" term used outside religious context.

Answer (score 7):

"Jewish" has several different meanings.

However "Judaism" [means](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Judaism):

> The religious doctrines and rites of the Jews, as enjoined in the laws of Moses.

The same dictionary has the traditional [definition](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Jew) of "Jew":

> *noun* [a contraction of Judas or Judah.] A Hebrew or Israelite.

In the United States, the Supreme Court held in [Shaare Tefila Congregation v. Cobb](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/481/615/case.html) that Jews were considered a distinct race at the time a previous law was passed, but that Jews are no longer considered a distinct race.

So "Judaism" refers to the religion, while "Jew" and "Jewish" can refer to ethnicity.

Comment: +1. Questions that aren't about religion (culture, ethnicity) shouldn't have "[judaism]" tag and should simply be retagged as being tagged errorneously.

Comment: After thinking about it, I think that @user5341 is right in the aproach, please add this to the answer so that I could accept it and then go and untag all the falsly tagged questions.

Answer (score -1):

I personally don't really mind, however it does make it a bit of a meta-tag. In this case it's probably appropriate as the concept itself is very fuzzy.

As long as this does not propagate to other religion tags, I'm OK with it.

Comment: I don't know why, but I wrote the exact opposite of what I meant in the last sentence. I've now fixed it.